# How to disable $_accessible protection for admin in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I was trying to do this pretty much time and now I quit.
In CakePHP 3 there is protection against mass assignment vulnerability by setting in Entity variable $_accessible. It's helpful against hackers but it's also very annoying when you build admin panel.
My question is how to disable this protection for all controllers with prefix="admin" and keep it for others?

- It can't be done in model beforeSave cause this is executed too late.
- I tried also create Behavior but it can't touch Entity, where things happen.
- The closest one was overwriting method newEntity() in a model but this way I must do it in every single model which is not very pretty solution.
- I know also it can be done in controller action when I'm saving data but writing it for every admin action... Well, there must be some better way.

Comment: You could create your own AppEntity class, which would extend Cake\ORM\Entity, and which your entities in turn extend. The __construct function of that class could set `$this->_accessible = ['*' => true];` if it's in an admin function, which you could test for by reading a config value that you conditionally write in AppController::beforeFilter.

Answer (score 0):

### Use guard false

This book solution is to use [the guard option](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#bypassing-field-guarding) e.g.

```
$article->set($properties, ['guard' => false]);
```

Also applies to [creating new entities](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#avoiding-mass-assignment-protection).

Adding `['guard' => false]` to relevant controller code shouldn't be *that* difficult, more or less find-and-replace and is less likely to cause problems in the future (accidentally disabling guard for none-admin actions).

### beforeMarshal

Alternatively, you could use [beforeMarshal](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#before-marshal) to modify the options injecting `guard => false`. Since you want that to be "all admin functions" the best way to do that would be to [register an anonymous event listener](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#registering-anonymous-listeners) for admin functions using [the global event manager](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#global-event-manager) along the lines of:

```
// Some controller
use Cake\Event\EventManager;

public function beforeFilter()
{
    EventManager::instance()->on(
        'Model.beforeMarshal',
        function ($event, $data, $options) {
            $options['guard'] = false;
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

create entity class in src/Model/Entity folder.and then define  protected

```
$_accessible = [
        '*' => true
    ];
```

Comment: That's [the default value](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Datasource/EntityTrait.php#L98-L109). Given the question the entities are baked and define accessible in each class, this won't have any effect.